# How do I fix a vector size error in Octave?

Tags: signal-processing, octave

```
%Linear Control system
%1: input signal, x(t) will be sampled 150 times at twice the nyquist rate
%2: x(t) = 2*cos(2*pi*t) + 5*cos(10*pi*t) + 3*cos(15*pi\*t);

clear;
clc;

n = 0:150;
Ts = 1/30;
t = n.\*Ts;
x = 2.\*cos(2.\*pi.\*t) + 5.\*cos(10.\*pi.\*t) + 3.\*cos(15.\*pi.\*t);

fc = 2;
negM = -2;
posM = 2;
k = negM:posM;

a = (sin((2.\*pi.\*fc.\*k)./ 30)./(k.*pi));
a(3) = 2.*( fc./ 30);
b = 0.54 +0.46.\*cos((k.\*pi)./posM);
h = a.\*b;

y = conv(h,x);

size(t)
size(y)
plot(t,x);
%plot(t,y)
```

The output for the size's are 151 and 155 respectively.

This is the error I get.

```
error: __plt2vv__: vector lengths must match
error: called from
__plt__\>__plt2vv__ at line 489 column 5
__plt__\>__plt2__ at line 248 column 14
__plt__ at line 115 column 16
plot at line 235 column 10

Projects name\* at line 30 column 1
```

How do I fix the code?

Comment: That is not legal Octave code. Please copy-paste the code exactly as it appears in your editor. You don’t need to escape special characters when it’s formatted as a code block.

Comment: Maybe you need to do `y = conv(x,h,"same")`?

Comment: @Cris luengo. Thank you i tried that but my i had the x and h swapped. it works. thanks